# How to change default error alert in react Google Charts?

Tags: reactjs, react-google-charts

How can I change the default react Google Charts error alert which looks like a red banner? I've made an event to listen to an error but I am unable to change its appearance.

```
{
     eventName:"error",
     callback({ chartWrapper }) {
     console.log("Error", chartWrapper)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that when you're getting information from an API, you can catch the error...

In the example they show in the documentation, you call an API as an async function

```
didMount={async function(component) {
    const response = await fetch(
      'https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?symbols=USD,GBP,CAD',
    )
    const json = await response.json()
    const rateCurrencyNames = Object.keys(json.rates)
    const rateCurrencyValues = Object.values(json.rates)
    const chartData = [['Currency Name', 'Currency Rate']]
    for (let i = 0; i < rateCurrencyNames.length; i += 1) {
      chartData.push([rateCurrencyNames[i], rateCurrencyValues[i]])
    }
    component.setState({
      dataLoadingStatus: 'ready',
      chartData: chartData,
    })
  }}
```

and pass it as props. In that one, you might want to catch the error with either a try and catch function and save it in a state, to render it out in your component.